# Moving Romex (or other NMB cable) to under the subfloor?

Tags: electrical

While pulling up some linoleum to later install some hardwood floors, I found a little surprise. Someone had carefully laid the wires down, nailed them, and put a protective piece of wood over them. A joist runs on both sides of the wires; I'm guessing it's doubled up because there used to be a load-bearing wall there or something. How should I remedy this?

[image: Romex on top of subfloor]

Comment: What's under this?

Comment: It's also hard to tell from the photo, but where are these wires running from? Is it possible to get closer to their (hopefully) common source and work from there?

Comment: I echo @Tester101 question, what is under this?  I'm assuming there is a wall on the first floor those wires are going down into.  Also where is the electrical panel in relation to this?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk they are running to a full height wall on the top of the photo. Tester101 and diceless, I think it is empty, a flashlight and inspection camera show nothing under it.

Comment: So it's a basement or crawl space underneath?

Comment: Basement. House is a bi-level with a large soffit in the 1st floor for the HVAC ducts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is something on the underside to prevent this, it would APPEAR that you should be able to drop the wires under the floor where they come down from above and turn - of course, that would require freeing up the wires so they can be re-pulled, or a mess of a junction box.

And there's the fact that this was not what was done to make me question if there is something blocking from below, or if it was just lazy weirdness when removing a wall that lead to this "interesting" approach.

Comment: I'll second this. Alternatively, might be easy enough to find an origin and destination, and make new runs. This may have been done previously because of inexperience and an odd request/project. I always find it's best to work as fresh as possible where cash and time allow.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this used to be a wall, wires came up, 90 degree at the usual height of an outlet and ran to the next wall. When they took the wall down, the wires had enough room to be laid on the floor. Add 1/2" of plywood and 1/4 of luan and you raised the floor enough to protect it. That is current theory.

Comment: @Josh it definitely looks like a wall was removed and the wiring rerouted.  But with 4 wires, it appears these are runs to different circuits inside your house and not just a reroute of one wall outlet.

Comment: Right, I think they are four separate circuits. I think the wall was used as the shortest way to run them to the upstairs for lighting around the HVAC ducts, water lines, and such. The other side is an open living room with a 2 foot overhang. Other option would be to run it to the outside wall. They couldn't run it to the wall it went too since the duct sits below it. Trying to understand the mind of an electrician 40 years ago who knows.